# How to use npm config (node-config) package with typescript configuration files?

Tags: node.js, typescript

The NPM [config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config) package supports Typescript configuration files.  The ts-node package is required to read the files.   However, when I add ts-node to my project, ts-node also attempts to compile the .ts files that comprise my node application, which have already been generated.  If I don't include ts-node, the config package errors out saying it needs ts-node.

Is there a way to configure ts-node so that it will only work on the configuration ts files in the config folder used by the `config` package? Alternately, is there a way to make the `config` package ignore the .ts files in the config folder, but use the generated .js files instead?

I am currently using .json5 but want the config files to be typed with an interface.

Comment: Far as I know, `ts-node` executes typescript files directly, and doesn't write any compiled js to the disk. What command are you using to invoke `ts-node`?

Comment: @AlexWayne I am not invoking ts-node.   I just include it in the dependencies in package.json and it starts trying to process the ts files in my application when I start node.  Perhaps this is a side effect of using the 'config' package.